# Technique to establish relation between content rating & conversion %

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, dataset, proportion

My blog has several pages, approx 250. Each one of them is some content written by me on that particular product (products are related to cosmetics). The pages have functionality to give rating (thumbs up and thumbs down). Each page has 2 to 3 call to action buttons which open a form in which user has to give name, email. We then call up the customer.

Technique to establish relation between content rating & conversion %

1. Content rating = thumbs up / (thumbs up + thumbs down) on each of page
2. Conversions = Total form submission / Total views on each page

both of them are proportional data.

Data looks like below

Page          % Rating (1)        Conversion Rate
X                15%                  2%
Y                20%                  3%
Z                30%                  4%

which statistical technique would be appropriate technique to establish relation between content rating & conversion %.

Comment: How many observations / responses do you have ?

Comment: what is X, Y , Z ?

Comment: There are around 5000 ratings of thumbs up /down for 250 blog posts
each blog post has 1000 views with average 100 form submissions

Comment: X Y Z are blog nos e.g. X has 15% thumbs up and 2% conversion
Y has 20% thumbs up and 3% conversion
Z has 30% thumbs up and 4% conversion

Comment: I guess correlation is not a good tool in this situation as both data sets are proportional data and correlation is good for continuous data

Comment: It is not yet clear  what  is the number of observations that are available for analysis and what is your hypothesis? what are your end goals ?

Comment: @subhash c. davar, as already mentioned, clarifying further in data set
there are 250 line items - one for each blog. Each blog has a % thumbsup and conversion %. Goal is to establish if there is a relationship between these two factors or not !

Answer (score 0):

Given the goal -  exploring whether there is a relationship between the proposed varables - you can categorize the content rating (say into two categories ) as well as conversation rates (say into five categories) and cross-classify the observed data and then, apply chi square test for checking whether there is an association between the two variables. The compution of  corelation coefficient between the two postlates (ratio based) is not recommended. Further, clarifications are solicited.

Comment: Looks appropriate approach, will try. However, expert comments for specific tool (correlation for both variables proportional) is sought for.

Comment: You may raise another question about correlation measure citing your aprehensions about the nature  of data.